# Bing Maps API returning different values to website

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

The API seems to be giving different values to the maps website.

Here is the front-end output for travelling between Manchester Airport and the London Eye.

[image: 1]

Here's the API output

[image: 2]

As you can see the numbers are close, but since they should both be calling the same thing, I'm confused as to the difference?

I need to use this to work out the time between close proximity places, so a couple of minutes matters here.

This is the api url I'm using:

[https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=53.361881,-2.270841&destinations=51.49984,-0.124663&travelMode=driving&timeUnit=minute&distanceUnit=mi&key={insertkey}](https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins=53.361881,-2.270841&destinations=51.49984,-0.124663&travelMode=driving&timeUnit=minute&distanceUnit=mi&key=%7Binsertkey%7D)

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The frontend website is using real time traffic data in its calculations. The Bing Maps route API supports calculations with real-time or predictive traffic data (estimated traffic). The distance matrix API only supports predictive traffic data, and only if you specify a start or end date, otherwise no traffic considerations is done. So, the distance matrix API is likely to be slightly different from the frontend site since real time traffic could differ from predicted traffic conditions. The distance matrix service is a batch service, designed for analysis purposes which generally looks at averages for future predictions, and not usually used for real time data scenarios.